# Why did a section of my Holly turn brown & fall off?

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, plant-care

I have a Goshiki Variegated False Holly & when we moved bought our home a month & half a go it was beautiful. It has now since turn mostly brown & the leaves have fallen off. The leaves did not turn black or have white spots on them. We have had well over 100 degree weather. I water at night once it cools down but this one is in the sun all day long. We have 2 of them & the other one is not doing this at all as it is in shade more. We did not plant these. Is there anything I can do try to save it. The branches are bendy, they are not weak or snappy.  [image][image][image]

Comment: a photo might be helpful (of both) to try to ascertain how long they've been planted by their size, assuming you don't know how long they've been in. Also, where are you in the world, and when you say you water at night, is that every night, and how exactly are you watering - with a can, standing  holding a hose and spray, sprinkler or something else?

Comment: I tried adding a photo but for some reason it won't let me. I water using an attachment. It has setting. I use the most setting first then a step back & use the shower setting for a 2 minutes & then water the base. I water every night unless we good a good rain as we did yesterday. So I won't water now for probably a day or two depending on the temperature.

Comment: I was able to add a picture!

Comment: Thank you so much. We had a good down poor yesterday for a good 45 minutes with some high winds.   I will definitely change my watering method! I haven't ever had these plants before & do not have a green thumb but are pretty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well the first thing to say is, your plant is by no means dead - I can see growth buds and even a tiny leaf starting to grow. It's hard to decide how long they've been planted - the one in the photo is a mature plant judging by the thickness of the mainstem, but the presence of a pristine label on which the print is clearly legible suggests it hasn't been planted that long.

It's your watering method that needs correction by the sound of it. Assuming this plant has not been in the ground for two years, it will need a really good soak (during hot, dry weather) at least once a week, and when I say a good soak, I mean the soil beneath it, not the top growth. It is better not to walk around with a hose and attachment, holding it yourself, and especially not every night. All that's going to do is wet the top couple of inches of soil, but the bottom of the rootball of your plant will be a good 6-9 inches below the top of the soil. The other effect of watering in that fashion is the plant will direct its roots towards the soil surface, because its learnt that you will come along and give it a little bit of water all the time - that's not what you want, you want the plant to put down roots to seek out its own water over time, so deep watering is necessary.

If you've had a lot of rain (hours of it, or torrential downpours) then okay, leave it for a couple of days, but then, either use a sprinkler attached to the hose, or just leave the hose trickling at the base of the plant, on the ground, for a good half an hour to an hour. If you choose the trickle method, move the hose to the other side of the plant after half an hour and leave it trickling till the hour is up. Don't repeat this for 5-7 days, depending on just how hot and dry it is. This method will ensure the water penetrates deep enough for the plant's roots. If you haven't had torrential rain, or hours of rain, water now, thoroughly, as described, for half an hour. If we assume this plant was purchased and planted just prior to sale, then the next year and a half is critical - after that, the roots should have spread deeper and wider and it will cope better with hot weather without frequent watering on your part.